# radio btn selection will show select list or text field, then that value querys and displays in another text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectbox

I have a form that when selecting the radio button it will query a database and populate either a select list or change select to a textbox for user input.(mostly working - won't go back to select after textbox - not as important now)

Then I want it to take the value from the select or textbox and put it in a string variable. Then I think I can take it from there. I hope. ( I will use string to query to get other info to populate bib numbers)

Here is my JS/php been trying everything

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bibfield = "";

    $('#a1').change(function () {
        //$('#hiddenText').hide();  
        $('#hidden').empty();
        //$('#hidden').show();
        $.each(arrayShort, function (i, val) {
            $('#hidden').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });
    });

    $('#a2').change(function () {
        //$('#hiddenText').hide();
        $('#hidden').empty();
        //$('#hidden').show();
        $.each(arrayLong, function (i, val) {
            $('#hidden').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });
    });

    $('#a3').change(function () {
        //$('#hidden').hide();
        //$('#hiddenText')show();

        $('#hidden').replaceWith('<input name="hidden" id="hiddenText" type="text" size="26" >');

    });
})
```

here is my form

```
<input name="btn1" id="a1" type="radio" value="Radio button 1" />
<input name="btn1" id="a2" type="radio" value="Radio button 2" />
<input name="btn1" id="a3" type="radio" value="Radio button 3" />
<select id="hidden" name="hidden">
  <option selected></option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="sBib" />
<input type="text" name="eBib" />
```

I need to populate the select if a1 or a2 is checked but if a3 is checked then I need to replace the select with a textbox **BUT Then populate a variable bibfield so I can query with it**.

New to this and I am so exhausted and can't think straight all help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

here you are replacing hidden with hiddenText and again trying to find the hidden which is gone already
 need to correct your code like below where i am replacing the whole select or input with same id="hidden"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var bibfield = "";
        // variable to indicate if select dropdown is available already otherwise create new
        var selectAvailable=true;
        $('#a1').change(function () {
            //$('#hiddenText').hide();  
            //$('#hidden').empty();
            //$('#hidden').show();
            $.each(arrayShort, function (i, val) {
                if(selectAvailable)
        {
        $('#hidden').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val+ '</option>');
        }
        else
        {
                selectAvailable=true;
            $('#hidden').replaceWith('<select id="hidden" name="hidden">
                <option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option></select>');
        }
            });
        });

        $('#a2').change(function () {
            //$('#hiddenText').hide();
           // $('#hidden').empty();
            //$('#hidden').show();
            $.each(arrayLong, function (i, val) {
            if(selectAvailable)
        {
            $('#hidden').append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        }
        else
        {
        selectAvailable=true;
            $('#hidden').replaceWith('<select id="hidden" name="hidden">
                <option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option></select>');
        }

        });

        $('#a3').change(function () {
            //$('#hidden').hide();
            //$('#hiddenText')show();
           selectAvailable=false;
            $('#hidden').replaceWith('<input name="hidden" id="hidden" type="text" size="26" >');

        });
    });
```